# why is my postgres process still running?

Tags: postgresql

I used 'sudo apt-get autoremove postgres' to uninstall the postgresql database on my local server. and I used 'sudo netstat -anpt' to find the the postgres is still there and is running? Why? Anybody to correct my understanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because a running process is in memory so it's independent of what's happening on the disk. It only matters if the running process needs to load something that's been removed. All you need to do is find the process id (`ps -aux`) then `kill -9 <pid>`.

Answer (score 1):

you can try a manual uninstallation (as root, assuming a default installation path):

```
/opt/PostgreSQL/8.3/installer/server/removeshortcuts.sh /opt/PostgreSQL/8.3 8.3
/etc/init.d postgresql-8.3 stop
rm -rf /opt/PostgreSQL
rm /etc/postgres-reg.ini
rm -rf /etc/init.d/postgresql-8.3
userdel postgres

if /etc/ld.so.conf exists, edit it and remove /opt/PostgreSQL/8.3/lib
if present.

if /etc/ld.so.conf.d exists:

rm /etc/ld.so.conf.d/postgresql-8.3.conf
```